# Using LIKE and IN and a Subquery in a single SQL Statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-like

I am writing a query in which I am trying to search a subquery/CTE for a wildcard substring, and nesting this logic in my CASE statement.  For example:

```
SELECT
CASE 
WHEN '%' + text + '%' IN (SELECT Column1 FROM Table) THEN 'I am in Column1'
ELSE text END
FROM Table
```

Unfortunately, it looks like there is no possibly way to do this.  Since I would need to use the LIKE operator and there is no way to use both LIKE and IN.  I would have to write each LIKE statement separately, and that would be for 1000+ rows.  Does anyone recommend a more immediate solution?  Thanks kindly in advance!

--
Edit: Sorry, some clarifications per comments.  A better example:

```
UserID     |  UserPeers   |  Gender
--------------------------------------------
Mike       |  Tom1, Bob1  |  M
John       |  Tom1, Greg1 |  M
Sally      |Mike1, John1  |  F
Sara       | Sally1, Bob1 |  F
```

In the above table, I need to search the substrings in UserPeers columns to see if they exist anywhere in the UserID column.  The rows that would be successfully returned in this case would be the ones under Sally and Sara, since 'Mike' and 'Sally' exist under UserID.

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE '%' + UserPeers + '%' LIKE (SELECT UserID FROM Users)
```

The error returned here is:
    Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Please clarify with some example data.  What about ANDing the conditions?

Comment: Not sure I follow. Do you just want to compare the `text` column with `Column1` in the same row? Is `text` a variable or a column name?

Comment: Thank you all for the extensive responses, Aaron's initial answer did the trick.  Got stuck on the LIKE.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT UserID, CASE WHEN EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserPeers LIKE '%' + u.UserID + '%'
) THEN 'I am in Column1' ELSE UserID END
FROM dbo.Users AS u;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.column1 like '%' + t.text + '%')
             then 'I am in Column1'
             ELSE t.text
        END)
FROM Table t;
```

Your original query seemed to have the wildcards on the wrong side of the `like`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't really need `Like` and `IN`

```
SELECT
CASE 
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table B WHERE B.COLUMN1 LIKE '%' + A.TEXT+ '%') THEN 'I am in Column1'
ELSE A.text END
FROM Table A
```

Comment: Don't you mean to correlate the subquery?

Comment: Yes, I mean correlate the subquery, but I'm not sure @thoughtExperiment need a key=key.

Comment: Not sure either. If I were given these requirements I would have thrown them back; in this case all we can do is guess. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

select
    case when (select count(*) from table where column1 like ('%' + text + '%')) > 0 then 'I am in column1'
    else text
    end
from table

Comment: Count can be quite expensive and wasteful when you don't care about the actual count. `EXISTS` is guaranteed to be no worse but can often be much better.